# R Replace cells with value 1 with a value from a corresponding column

Tags: r, replace

I have a data frame of presence (1) or absence (NA) of various plants found in different quadrats. I have 5 columns within the data frame of values that I would like to replace the 1's with. I'd like to end up with 5 different data frames.

#### Current Data Frame

This is a section of the data frame. Each row is a different plant. The columns L, F, R, N and S are the values I wish to replace the values win the last size columns ('1_19', '1_20' etc). Where there are blanks/NAs I want to keep them as blanks.

[image]

#### Expected Output

This is an example of the expected output for the L column. I would like to do this for the other columns too as separate dfs.

[image]

#### Data Frame

```
structure(list(Species = c("Conocephalum conicum", "Mnium hornum", 
"Polytrichum formosum", "Oxalis acetosella", "Circaea lutetiana", 
"Geum urbanum"), Common.Name = c("Great Scented Liverwort", "Swan's-neck Thyme-moss", 
"Bank Haircap", "Wood Sorrel", "Enchanter's-nightshade", "Wood Avens"
), L = c(3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), F = c(7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), R = c(6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L), N = c(5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L
), S = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Source = c("Hill et al., 2007", 
"Hill et al., 2007", "Hill et al., 2007", "Hill et al., 1999", 
"Hill et al., 1999", "Hill et al., 1999"), X1_19 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L), X1_20 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), X1_22 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), X2_19 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X2_20 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), X2_22 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X3_19 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), 
    X3_20 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X3_22 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X4_19 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), X4_20 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X4_22 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X5_19 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), X5_20 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X5_22 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X6_19 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), X6_20 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1L, NA), X6_22 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), X7_19 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), X7_20 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), X7_22 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), X8_19 = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), X8_20 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), X8_22 = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), X9_19 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), X9_20 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), X9_22 = c(NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired output for all variables L..S, we could `pivot_longer` these variables, mutate across all variables starting with X, and use the grouping to split into 5 dataframes:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
    pivot_longer(L:S) |>
    relocate(c(name, value), .before = "Species") |>
    group_by(name) |>
    mutate(across(starts_with("X"), ~ if_else(!is.na(.), value, NA_integer_))) |>
    group_split()
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 × 32
  name  value Species     Common.Name Source X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22
  <chr> <int> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 F         7 Conocephal… Great Scen… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 F         5 Mnium horn… Swan's-nec… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3 F         6 Polytrichu… Bank Hairc… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 F         6 Oxalis ace… Wood Sorrel Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 F         6 Circaea lu… Enchanter'… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 F         6 Geum urban… Wood Avens  Hill …     6     6     6    NA    NA    NA     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# … with 15 more variables: X5_19 <int>, X5_20 <int>, X5_22 <int>, X6_19 <int>, X6_20 <int>, X6_22 <int>,
#   X7_19 <int>, X7_20 <int>, X7_22 <int>, X8_19 <int>, X8_20 <int>, X8_22 <int>, X9_19 <int>, X9_20 <int>,
#   X9_22 <int>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 × 32
  name  value Species     Common.Name Source X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22
  <chr> <int> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 L         3 Conocephal… Great Scen… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 L         4 Mnium horn… Swan's-nec… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3 L         4 Polytrichu… Bank Hairc… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 L         4 Oxalis ace… Wood Sorrel Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 L         4 Circaea lu… Enchanter'… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 L         4 Geum urban… Wood Avens  Hill …     4     4     4    NA    NA    NA     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# … with 15 more variables: X5_19 <int>, X5_20 <int>, X5_22 <int>, X6_19 <int>, X6_20 <int>, X6_22 <int>,
#   X7_19 <int>, X7_20 <int>, X7_22 <int>, X8_19 <int>, X8_20 <int>, X8_22 <int>, X9_19 <int>, X9_20 <int>,
#   X9_22 <int>

[[3]]
# A tibble: 6 × 32
  name  value Species     Common.Name Source X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22
  <chr> <int> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 N         5 Conocephal… Great Scen… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 N         4 Mnium horn… Swan's-nec… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3 N         3 Polytrichu… Bank Hairc… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 N         4 Oxalis ace… Wood Sorrel Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 N         6 Circaea lu… Enchanter'… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 N         7 Geum urban… Wood Avens  Hill …     7     7     7    NA    NA    NA     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# … with 15 more variables: X5_19 <int>, X5_20 <int>, X5_22 <int>, X6_19 <int>, X6_20 <int>, X6_22 <int>,
#   X7_19 <int>, X7_20 <int>, X7_22 <int>, X8_19 <int>, X8_20 <int>, X8_22 <int>, X9_19 <int>, X9_20 <int>,
#   X9_22 <int>

[[4]]
# A tibble: 6 × 32
  name  value Species     Common.Name Source X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22
  <chr> <int> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 R         6 Conocephal… Great Scen… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 R         4 Mnium horn… Swan's-nec… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3 R         3 Polytrichu… Bank Hairc… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 R         4 Oxalis ace… Wood Sorrel Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 R         7 Circaea lu… Enchanter'… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 R         7 Geum urban… Wood Avens  Hill …     7     7     7    NA    NA    NA     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# … with 15 more variables: X5_19 <int>, X5_20 <int>, X5_22 <int>, X6_19 <int>, X6_20 <int>, X6_22 <int>,
#   X7_19 <int>, X7_20 <int>, X7_22 <int>, X8_19 <int>, X8_20 <int>, X8_22 <int>, X9_19 <int>, X9_20 <int>,
#   X9_22 <int>

[[5]]
# A tibble: 6 × 32
  name  value Species     Common.Name Source X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22
  <chr> <int> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 S         0 Conocephal… Great Scen… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 S         0 Mnium horn… Swan's-nec… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3 S         0 Polytrichu… Bank Hairc… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 S         0 Oxalis ace… Wood Sorrel Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 S         0 Circaea lu… Enchanter'… Hill …    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 S         0 Geum urban… Wood Avens  Hill …     0     0     0    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# … with 15 more variables: X5_19 <int>, X5_20 <int>, X5_22 <int>, X6_19 <int>, X6_20 <int>, X6_22 <int>,
#   X7_19 <int>, X7_20 <int>, X7_22 <int>, X8_19 <int>, X8_20 <int>, X8_22 <int>, X9_19 <int>, X9_20 <int>,
#   X9_22 <int>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr, this should work :

```
L=df%>%
  rowwise()%>% 
  mutate_at(.vars=colnames(df)[9:35],funs(replace(., which(.==1), L)))
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's a relatively simple version using `purrr` to get your 5 data frames (as list elements). The selection of the columns `X1_...` can of course be changed to your liking.

```
check_names <- c("L", "F", "R", "N", "S")

library(tidyverse)

check_names |> 
  map(\(current_name) df |>
      select(-setdiff(check_names, current_name)) |> 
      rowwise() |> 
      mutate(across(matches("^X\\d+_\\d"), ~ifelse(is.na(.), ., .data[[current_name]]))) |>
      ungroup()) |>
  set_names(check_names)

$L
# A tibble: 6 × 31
  Species              Common.Name                 L Source            X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22 X5_19 X5_20 X5_22 X6_19 X6_20 X6_22 X7_19 X7_20 X7_22 X8_19 X8_20 X8_22 X9_19 X9_20 X9_22
  <chr>                <chr>                   <int> <chr>             <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Conocephalum conicum Great Scented Liverwort     3 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3    NA     3    NA    NA    NA
2 Mnium hornum         Swan's-neck Thyme-moss      4 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     4     4     4
3 Polytrichum formosum Bank Haircap                4 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     4    NA     4    NA    NA    NA
4 Oxalis acetosella    Wood Sorrel                 4 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA        4    NA     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 Circaea lutetiana    Enchanter's-nightshade      4 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA     4    NA    NA     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 Geum urbanum         Wood Avens                  4 Hill et al., 1999     4     4     4    NA    NA    NA     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

$F
# A tibble: 6 × 31
  Species              Common.Name                 F Source            X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22 X5_19 X5_20 X5_22 X6_19 X6_20 X6_22 X7_19 X7_20 X7_22 X8_19 X8_20 X8_22 X9_19 X9_20 X9_22
  <chr>                <chr>                   <int> <chr>             <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Conocephalum conicum Great Scented Liverwort     7 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     7    NA     7    NA    NA    NA
2 Mnium hornum         Swan's-neck Thyme-moss      5 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     5     5     5
3 Polytrichum formosum Bank Haircap                6 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     6    NA     6    NA    NA    NA
4 Oxalis acetosella    Wood Sorrel                 6 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA        6    NA     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 Circaea lutetiana    Enchanter's-nightshade      6 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA     6    NA    NA     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 Geum urbanum         Wood Avens                  6 Hill et al., 1999     6     6     6    NA    NA    NA     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

$R
# A tibble: 6 × 31
  Species              Common.Name                 R Source            X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22 X5_19 X5_20 X5_22 X6_19 X6_20 X6_22 X7_19 X7_20 X7_22 X8_19 X8_20 X8_22 X9_19 X9_20 X9_22
  <chr>                <chr>                   <int> <chr>             <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Conocephalum conicum Great Scented Liverwort     6 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     6    NA     6    NA    NA    NA
2 Mnium hornum         Swan's-neck Thyme-moss      4 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     4     4     4
3 Polytrichum formosum Bank Haircap                3 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3    NA     3    NA    NA    NA
4 Oxalis acetosella    Wood Sorrel                 4 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA        4    NA     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 Circaea lutetiana    Enchanter's-nightshade      7 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA     7    NA    NA     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 Geum urbanum         Wood Avens                  7 Hill et al., 1999     7     7     7    NA    NA    NA     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

$N
# A tibble: 6 × 31
  Species              Common.Name                 N Source            X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22 X5_19 X5_20 X5_22 X6_19 X6_20 X6_22 X7_19 X7_20 X7_22 X8_19 X8_20 X8_22 X9_19 X9_20 X9_22
  <chr>                <chr>                   <int> <chr>             <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Conocephalum conicum Great Scented Liverwort     5 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     5    NA     5    NA    NA    NA
2 Mnium hornum         Swan's-neck Thyme-moss      4 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     4     4     4
3 Polytrichum formosum Bank Haircap                3 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3    NA     3    NA    NA    NA
4 Oxalis acetosella    Wood Sorrel                 4 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA        4    NA     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 Circaea lutetiana    Enchanter's-nightshade      6 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA     6    NA    NA     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 Geum urbanum         Wood Avens                  7 Hill et al., 1999     7     7     7    NA    NA    NA     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

$S
# A tibble: 6 × 31
  Species              Common.Name                 S Source            X1_19 X1_20 X1_22 X2_19 X2_20 X2_22 X3_19 X3_20 X3_22 X4_19 X4_20 X4_22 X5_19 X5_20 X5_22 X6_19 X6_20 X6_22 X7_19 X7_20 X7_22 X8_19 X8_20 X8_22 X9_19 X9_20 X9_22
  <chr>                <chr>                   <int> <chr>             <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Conocephalum conicum Great Scented Liverwort     0 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA     0    NA    NA    NA
2 Mnium hornum         Swan's-neck Thyme-moss      0 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     0     0     0
3 Polytrichum formosum Bank Haircap                0 Hill et al., 2007    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     0    NA     0    NA    NA    NA
4 Oxalis acetosella    Wood Sorrel                 0 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA        0    NA     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 Circaea lutetiana    Enchanter's-nightshade      0 Hill et al., 1999    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA     0    NA    NA     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 Geum urbanum         Wood Avens                  0 Hill et al., 1999     0     0     0    NA    NA    NA     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thankyou! How can you do this so that each tibble is named with the relevant 'check_names' letter? As opposed to 1-5

Comment: See my update above. simply `set_names`

Comment: Is there a way to make it Q1_19 instead of X1_19 for example. When I've changed to X in the code the rest doesnt work.

Comment: This is based ony oru input data, which produces columns "X1_..." and so on. If your column names are sth. like "Q1_19", "Q2_19" and so on, please check the `matches` part in my code above and in that case replace teh X by a Q. Of course, if you have other naming patterns, you might need to rethink this.